# Flutter: pass a fuction parameter through class constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 classes `TasksTile` and `TaskCheckbox`. So I need to pass 2 parameters form `TasksTile` to `TaskCheckbox`. So I created a constructor on `TaskCheckbox` with 2 parameters

I want to pass those parameters from `TasksTile` as

```
// TasksTile class
return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'data',
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(isChecked, checkboxCallBack), // passing those
    );
```

my fuunction  :

```
// TasksTile class
  void checkboxCallBack(bool checkboxState) {
    setState(() {
      isChecked = checkboxState;
    });
  }
```

my constructor:

```
//TaskCheckbox class
TaskCheckbox(this.checkboxState, this.toggleCheckboxstate); // this is my constructor
    final bool checkboxState; 
    final  Function toggleCheckboxstate;
```

then I just assigned the parameters to the code as

```
//TaskCheckbox class
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState, // this is the fisrt one and it is bool so it works fine.
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxstate, // this is the seconde one it is a Fucntion and here is the problem 
    );
  }
```

I got an error here `onChanged: toggleCheckboxstate,` said : The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.
I think the problem is in here `final  Function toggleCheckboxstate;` it is works fine in older flutter but not in the latest version.

Comment: try changing it into: `final ValueChanged<bool?> toggleCheckboxState`. Also change this `void checkboxCallBack(bool checkboxState)` to this `void checkboxCallBack(bool? checkboxState)`.

Comment: i dont get it. i tried your code but its gives me more errors. i tried to fix it more but it did not work. @h8moss

Comment: just remove the final from the constructor final  Function toggleCheckboxstate

Comment: @RehamAlraee Same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case here is the solution:

```
  TaskCheckbox({this.checkboxState, this.toggleCheckboxstate});
  final bool? checkboxState;
  final void Function(bool?)? toggleCheckboxstate; // here what had been chenged
```

and then changed the function also

```
  void checkboxCallBack(checkboxState) { //Removed bool from (bool checkboxState)
    setState(() {
      isChecked = checkboxState;
    });
   }
```

Comment: that is how I solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
trailing: TaskCheckbox(checkboxState: isChecked, toggleCheckboxstate: (bool checkboxState) {
 setState(() {
      isChecked = checkboxState;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I got: "The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'"

Comment: so just change the above code to : trailing: TaskCheckbox(checkboxState: isChecked, toggleCheckboxstate: (bool? checkboxState) {
 setState(() {
      isChecked = checkboxState;
    });
});